# define a different size for font for different html elements

Tags: html, css

creating a basic image card and i need to adjust the size of the headers the first header needs to be 22px and the second needs to be 11px.
im new to html so i really dont know where to go from the code i have built., Im using visual studio code to write my command line.

```html
<!--cards -->

<div class="card">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2018/02/People-in-the-desert-experience-camel-travel-Stock-Photo-01.jpg" alt="a man in the desert" width=4 0px; height=192px>
  </div>
  <div class="title">


    <h1>
      Title goes here </h1>

    <h2>
      Secondary text</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="des">
    <p>Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p>

  </div>
  <!--cards -->
```

Answer (score 0):

That's were css is used:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2018/02/People-in-the-desert-experience-camel-travel-Stock-Photo-01.jpg" alt="a man in the desert" width=40px; height=192px>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Secondary text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="des">
    <p>Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `font-size`

```html
<!--cards -->

<div class="card">

  <div class="image">
     <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2018/02/People-in-the-desert-experience-camel-travel-Stock-Photo-01.jpg" alt="a man in the desert" width= 40px; height=192px>
  </div>
  <div class="title">


    <h1 style="font-size:22px;">
  Title goes here </h1>

  <h2 style="font-size:11px;">
    Secondary text</h2>

 </div>

  <div class="des">
   <p>Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p>

  </div>
  <!--cards -->
```

Comment: inline style should be avoided where possible (and this is the case) in favor of CSS stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve it by using CSS...
There are 3 ways of adding your style sheet as you can review here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

in your case the CSS property will be helpful for you is **font-size** property. And the html elements  you want to manipulate is : h1 and h2;
safest way to do it as a beginner in my opinion adding the css file inside of your html head tag with a style tag like this:

> h1 {   font-size:22px; } h2 { font-size:11px; }
>
> ```
> <h1>
>   Title goes here </h1>
>
> <h2>
>   Secondary text</h2>
> ```
>
> Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.